# ggplot2 data frame with int, num and factor

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data in table format:

- TemperatureC: 0,12,19,24,24,24
- SalinityPPT: 18.5, 33, 7, 7, 18.5, 33
- MOR: E, E, E, A, A, A

With structure:

```
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ TemperatureC: int  0 12 19 24 24 24
 $ SalinityPPT : num  18.5 33 7 7 18.5 33
 $ MOR         : Factor w/ 2 levels "A","E": 2 2 2 1 1 1
```

I want to obtain a point graph with the salinity and temperature in the x and y axis depicting the mortality (A or E) in the corresponding xy coordinates.

I have been trying the following code with `ggplot2`:

```
morg<- ggplot(data = mor, mapping = aes(x = TemperatureC, y =     SalinityPPT)) 


morg + geom_point(aes(color = MOR))
```

Also, I tried converting the numeric to interval, but nothing has worked so far.

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two options: Names shortened. You can use names in the original data set.

One:

```
df<-data.frame(Temp=c(0,12,19,24,24,24),Salinity=c(18.5, 33, 7, 7, 18.5, 33),
               MOR=c(rep("E",3),rep("A",3)))
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(df,aes(Temp,Salinity,col=MOR))+geom_point()
```

Two:

```
df %>% 
  gather("ID","Val",-MOR) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(ID,Val,col=MOR))+geom_point()
```